# Expresion regular en python que tenga un patron en base a la estructura de una oracion

Tags: python, python-3.x, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy haciendo un analizador lingüístico en python, en base a las oraciones simples:
ARTICULO + SUJETO + VERBO + PREDICADO. Necesito saber o de que otra forma podría validar una oración en ese orden. Mi diccionario de datos los tengo ya definidos como:

```
articulos={} 
sujetos={}
verbos{}
predicado{}
```

Comment: Quizás te interese `spacy`

Comment: creo que si, lo ocupare para hacer el analizador semántico. Gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Para crear una expresión regular que tome como patrón una oración simple en español con la estructura "Artículo + Sujeto + Verbo + Predicado", se puede utilizar los diccionarios definidos en Python para definir cada una de estas partes de la oración.
```

Por ejemplo, podríamos utilizar los siguientes diccionarios:

python

articulos = {'el', 'la', 'los', 'las', 'un', 'una', 'unos', 'unas'}
sujetos = {'yo', 'tú', 'él', 'ella', 'usted', 'nosotros', 'nosotras', 'vosotros', 'vosotras', 'ellos', 'ellas', 'ustedes'}
verbos = {'correr', 'saltar', 'bailar', 'cantar', 'escribir', 'leer', 'comer', 'beber', 'amar', 'odiar', 'querer', 'necesitar', 'gustar', 'parecer', 'tener', 'ser', 'estar', 'ir', 'venir'}
predicados = {'una pizza', 'la canción', 'mucho', 'nada', 'en la playa', 'con mi amigo', 'a la universidad', 'temprano', 'tarde', 'ayer', 'mañana'}

Con estos diccionarios, podemos crear una expresión regular que busque la presencia de un artículo, seguido de un sujeto, un verbo y un predicado:

python

```
import re

articulos = {'el', 'la', 'los', 'las', 'un', 'una', 'unos', 'unas'}
sujetos = {'yo', 'tú', 'él', 'ella', 'usted', 'nosotros', 'nosotras', 'vosotros', 'vosotras', 'ellos', 'ellas', 'ustedes'}
verbos = {'correr', 'saltar', 'bailar', 'cantar', 'escribir', 'leer', 'comer', 'beber', 'amar', 'odiar', 'querer', 'necesitar', 'gustar', 'parecer', 'tener', 'ser', 'estar', 'ir', 'venir'}
predicados = {'una pizza', 'la canción', 'mucho', 'nada', 'en la playa', 'con mi amigo', 'a la universidad', 'temprano', 'tarde', 'ayer', 'mañana'}

pattern = r'^(' + '|'.join(articulos) + r') (' + '|'.join(sujetos) + r') (' + '|'.join(verbos) + r') (' + '|'.join(predicados) + r')$'

sentence = 'La vaca come pasto'

if re.match(pattern, sentence):
    print('La oración cumple el patrón')
else:
    print('La oración no cumple el patrón')
```

Comment: Las respuestas deben ser demostradas. El código que proporcionas responde con `La oración no cumple el patrón`. Corrigelo o eliminalo.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).